Not being able to use source action in vscode
Everytime I use source action for any purpose I get message like this
"command 'nbls.java.generate.toString' not found"enter image description here.
Note that the IDE I am using is vscode.
I am trying to generate toString() from source action

Hello, this may be due to a missing plugin or plugin configuration. Do you have the Java extension pack installed? What are the error messages in the output window in vscode? You can check if Java and its version are installed by typing java -version in the terminal.
